# How do I bind a non database column value to repeater label using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a little challenge that I can't get around. I have a result from the code below.

```
if (Request.Cookies["ProductRecord"] != null)
{
    s = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["ProductRecord"].Value);
    string[] strArr = s.Split('|');
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
    {
        t = Convert.ToString(strArr[i].ToString());
        string[] strArr1 = t.Split(',');
        for (int j = 0; j < strArr1.Length; j++)
        {
            a[j] = strArr1[j].ToString();

        }
        SingleCount = (Convert.ToDecimal(a[1].ToString()) * Convert.ToDecimal(a[3].ToString()));

    }
}
```

How do I bind the results of `SingleCount` to a label inside a repeater.

`RepeaterId.DataSource = SingleCount` is the closest i have thought of but its not working.

Comment: You should clarify:
1. is your Label an ASP.net Label control
2. You will have several values for SingleCount which one to you want for your label ? will you want all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions based upon your code so I may be off-base on what you're trying to achieve, but couldn't you take SingleCount and add it to a list of decimals and then bind that list to the DataSource of your repeater?